# Counting in two ways

Tags: combinatorics

I've been having trouble proving the following equivalence. I suspect a two-way counting  method is sufficient. Could anyone shed some light?
$$\sum_{i=0}^{m}{ \binom{n-i}{m-i} \binom{k+i}{i}} =\binom{n+k+1}{m}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start off with one pile on the left containing n-m red balls and m green balls, and another pile to on the right with exactly k blue balls. Count the number of ways that the left pile can have its red and green balls arranged (ie n chose m) multiplied by the number of ways (ie 1) that the right pile can have its red balls arranged. Then move 1 green ball from the left pile to the right pile and count again. Keep doing this until all green balls are on the right, and then add up each term. The answer is the left hand side of your equation, and is essentially the number of ways of distributing m green balls among two piles, one with n-m red balls, the other with k blue balls.

This procedure is equivalent to lining up all the red balls in a row, followed by one black ball, and then all the blue balls in a row. We then place the m green balls between any of the balls that were just laid down. If a green ball is to the left of the black ball, then it is said to be "in the left pile", otherwise, it's "in the right pile". 
The total number of balls is n+k+1 (since we have now included a demarcating black ball). The number of arrangements is this n+k+1 choose m.